# How to track token transfers on Solana?

Tags: web3js, solana

I know that to track transactions on Ethereum you should use web3 or ethers WebSocket provider and listen to specific events, then filter by logs if needed. How similar thing can be done on Solana?

My guess is to use [Connection class](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html) from [web3.js](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/index.html) and onLogs method, but I do not know how to construct log filters and I could not find any example. Anyone has experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track all transactions on Solana, you can use the currently new and unstable `blockSubscribe` method, which sends you whole blocks with all the transactions within.  You can add additional filtering for a program or account that you care about: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#blocksubscribe---unstable-disabled-by-default

Otherwise, if you only care about transfers, you can only subscribe to the system program (`11111111111111111111111111111111`) for SOL transfers, and the SPL Token program (`TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`) for any other transfers using the `programSubscribe` endpoint: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#programsubscribe

Comment: These subscriptions only listen to new changes correct? What if we are interested in transfers that already happened? Should we query all transactions and filter on token transfers?

Comment: Correct, you'd have to query all transactions going backwards, either using `getBlock` and searching through all transactions, or by using `getSignaturesForAddress` to get all signatures referencing the program that you care about, then `getTransaction` for each signature returned